# How to increase a variables' value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I am building a canvas game just for some canvas practice. What it is is a picture of just the slide of a gun, and then right under it is a picture of the whole thing minus th slide, so it looks like one picture of a gun. When the canvas is clicked, I am going to make the slide go back then forward again, and a bullet is going to travel out of the barrel. I need help though finding ways to get the bullet to move. I tried increasing the value of the x coordinate variable, and maybe I just wasn't doing something right there, but it didn't work.
Do you guys have any suggestions for me?

Thank you very much, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I can't visualize without code.

Comment: Impossible to answer this without seeing your code.  We can't guess

Comment: really don't need all the visual details... show how it works!

Comment: Does anyone know a psychic?

Comment: I think he wants some basic animation advice.

Comment: Did you set up the animation loop so it updates the canvas every x milliseconds? If you have changed a variable, it should be reflected on the canvas if this invalidation loop is setup correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I suspect you didn't set up the animation loop correctly. Inside of your javascript write something like this

```
var gameThread = SetInterval(invalidate, 33);
function invalidate(){
    updateBulletX();
    redrawCanvas();
}
```

So about 30 times in one second, invalidate function will run. updateBulletX function will calculate the current position of the bullet, and the redrawCanvas function will wipe out and redraw the whole canvas.

This is a fundamental concept of any animation based games.

I encourage you to use a game engine based on canvas to make your life a bit easier.

- http://impactjs.com/
- http://canvasengine.net/
- http://enchantjs.com/

etc etc google

Answer (score 1):

Just increasing the variable won't cause the canvas to redraw. You must manually redraw the canvas to show the scene in its new, updated state.